# How to reduce lines of code of too big java file with automated tools.?

Tags: java

I am working on one of the legacy project having 5000 java files and there are more than 100 java files having total lines of code > 8000 lines in it and i want to break it down . 
For instance "foo.java" has total 9587 lines of code inside it and i need to fine tune it with the help of say divide and conquer strategy. 
As there are many such files in my project i wanted to develop some automated rules which does it(separating large java files into smaller one) periodically.
Though doing it manually is the last option but i still want to know if there are any tools / plug-ins that helps to do it automatically ?

Please share your thoughts on the same.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and time .

Comment: Odds are, when you have over 8000 lines in one single file, you'll have to do it by hand - there's only so much the automated tools can do before they explode. If it looks like someone wrote C, then ported it to Java, then a good tool to look for would be one that can show a dependency graph for all the functions.

Comment: I don't know if there's a tool that will do that automatically, but at last sonarQube might help you find duplicate code. Are these huge class instantiated ? or are they "utils class" with mostly static methods ?

Comment: thanks for sharing your thoughts. these classes are the real objects which are utilized to useful work. i already scan the project with sonar to clean up the technical debt. it is very helpful in many aspect.

Answer (score 1):

With files this big you shouldn't be using automated tools to split them.
As some colleagues have mentioned you can use tools to spot duplicate code.
Be careful with duplicates though, sometimes they are just accidentally duplicated, meaning, they might be similar at the moment, but they are not related domains and they will probably evolve differently over time.
You will have to start pulling out code into separate classes one at a time.
I'd even recommend you use the "One public method per class" method, so that you can have many small, easy to understand and reuse classes in the end.